# WPF Thumb Drag and Drop only on a specific control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on a part of a WPF application that takes a number of controls wrapped in Thumb tags and there will be "wells" that will be able to accept only specific Thumb controls. I wrote a very simple example to demonstrate what I'm working with.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="DragDropExample2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DragDropExample2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Canvas>
    <Thumb x:Name="Circle" Canvas.Right="10" Canvas.Top="20" DragDelta="Thumb_OnDragDelta">
        <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Ellipse x:Name="circleUI" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Blue"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Thumb.Template>
    </Thumb>
    <Ellipse x:Name="circleWell" Height="100" Width="100" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Bottom="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"/>
</Canvas>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Thumb_OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement thumb = e.Source as UIElement;

        Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange);
        Canvas.SetTop(thumb, Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange);
    }
}
```

So, in essence what I want to do is have the animation of dragging the blue circle and only be able to drop it in the empty circle, perhaps when the mouse is inside of the empty circle. Dropping it anywhere else on the page would return it to it's original position. I don't know if it'd be possible to get the mouse events that are being kept by the Thumb control to be accessible by the rest of the application.

What I would like help with is checking whether or not the control, in this case the circleWell, is under the Circle Thumb control and therefore is a valid drop. Otherwise return Circle to it's origin point.

I thought maybe doing a DragCompleted event comparing the mouse position to the range of values of the target (Circle) would be a good way to do this, but I would prefer it if dropping the Circle could be prevented if it's not within acceptable bounds. If preventing drop is not possible I'm fine with working with the DragCompleted event. My desired workflow would be returning Circle to it's starting position if the coordinates of the mouse are not within the circleWell boundaries, otherwise, if the Circle is within acceptable bounds I would like it(Circle) to "snap" to cover the container control (circleWell).

Comment: _"it's stumping me"_ -- how, specifically, is it stumping you? What have you tried? What did that code do? What did you want it to do instead? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise description of what specifically you're having trouble with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I added some clarification and additional information to the original question. Sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a custom cursor of the control that is clicked on and the drag and drop is based on a boolean value.